# How to flatten list inside RDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Is it possible to flatten list inside RDD? For example convert:

```
 val xxx: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[List[Foo]]
```

to:

```
 val yyy: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Foo]
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array(List(1,2,3), List(4,5,6), List(7,8,9), List(10, 11, 12)))
// org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[List[Int]] = ParallelCollectionRDD ...

val rddi = rdd.flatMap(list => list)
// rddi: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = FlatMappedRDD ...

// which is same as rdd.flatMap(identity)
// identity is a method defined in Predef object.
//    def identity[A](x: A): A

rddi.collect()
// res2: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)
```

Answer (score 14):

You just need to flatten it, but as there's no explicit 'flatten'  method on RDD, you can do this:

```
rdd.flatMap(identity)
```

Comment: Thanks. What in this case is `rdd` and what is `identity`? How does your answer translate to an example in my question?

Comment: @zork it would be `xxx.flatMap(identity)` in the question. `identity` is a predefined function that's as it says, the identity function. You probably already know this already, though.