# Merge list of lists in pySpark RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have lists of tuples that I want to combine into one list.  I've been able to process the data using lambdas and list comprehension to where I'm close to being able to use reduceByKey but not sure how to merge the lists.  So the format...

```
[[(0, 14), (0, 24)], [(1, 19), (1, 50)], ...]
```

And I would like it to be this way....

```
[(0, 14), (0, 24), (1, 19), (1, 50), ...]
```

Code that got me to where I need to be...

```
test = test.map(lambda x: (x[1], [e * local[x[1]] for e in x[0]]))
test = test.map(lambda x: [(x[0], y) for y in x[1]])
```

But not sure from there what to do to merge the lists

Comment: use `flatten` instead of manually exploding.

Comment: Hmm.  Ok I thought about that but for some reason didn't think it was the way to go.  I'll have a look

Comment: you can even do `test.flatMap(identity)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do,

```
test = test.flatMap(identity)
```

or

```
test = test.flatMap(lambda list: list)
```

Comment: Check this [link for Scala and Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28233405/1592191)

Comment: What is identity?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @mrsrinivas for providing the hint...

test = test.flatMap(lambda xs: [(x[0], x[1]) for x in xs])