# How to flatten RDD of sequences

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sequence, rdd

I currently have an `RDD[Seq[MatrixEntry]]` that I am attempting to transform into an `RDD[MatrixEntry]` simply by unwrapping or flattening the `Seq`. I can convert the `Seq` into other datatypes such as `List`, but I am unable to remove it altogether.

My problem is strikingly similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28233405/how-to-flatten-list-inside-rdd), as I can transform the `Seq`, but with `MatrixEntry` instead of Ints, yet attempting a solution similar to that yields

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.MatrixEntry
 required: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]
```

The code I am trying to run is trying to transform a DataFrame into a CoordinateMatrix:

```
def matmaker(data: DataFrame):Unit={
    val rrd:RDD[(List[(Any,Int)],Long)] = data.rdd
        .map(r => r.toSeq.toList.zipWithIndex)
        .zipWithIndex()
    val precord:RDD[MatrixEntry] = rrd.map{
      case ((s:Seq[(Any,Int)],r:Long)) => s.map{
        case (value:Any,c:Int) => MatrixEntry(r,c,value.toString.toDouble)
      }.flatMap(List => List) //Problem Here
    }
    precord.foreach(println)
    //new CoordinateMatrix(precord.map(r=>r.take(r.length-1)))
  }
```

The final typing of the function will be changed from `Unit` to `CoordinateMatrix` once I'm done testing.

Comment: Can you show us the code, with type annotations, that you're running?

Comment: @Ethan Just edited

Comment: Change this: `val precord:RDD[MatrixEntry] = rrd.map{` with: `val precord:RDD[MatrixEntry] = rrd.flatMap {` and remove this: `.flatMap(List => List)`.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez It worked! Thank you so much. Would you like to post it as an answer so that I can credit you?

Comment: @Cheezbeez neh, no worries, it was just a novice mistake. Always remember, if you want to flatten the results of a function use `flatMap` otherwise use `map` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your flatmap is simply misplaced.

Instead of `}.flatMap(x=>x)}`you need to write `}}.flatMap(x=>x)`like this:

```scala
def matmaker(data: DataFrame):CoordinateMatrix={
    val rrd:RDD[(List[(Any,Int)],Long)] = data.rdd
        .map(r => r.toSeq.toList.zipWithIndex)
        .zipWithIndex()
    val precord:RDD[MatrixEntry] = rrd.map{
        case ((s:Seq[(Any,Int)],r:Long)) => s.map{
            case (value:Any,c:Int) => MatrixEntry(r,c,value.toString.toDouble)
        }//No Problem Here, flatmap was moved
    }.flatMap(x => x) 
    new CoordinateMatrix(precord)
}
```